How to add monitoring and use the spring boot actuator endpoints
In our Camunda based service we had to change the actuator endpoints to be under the “/" probePath to enable health checks within the pod.
**
I’m using java version17, camunda 7.21.0, spring boot version 3.2.1
Any idea about this one?
We couldn’t find any solution make any updates necessary to work with this path.
And when we try to use the spring boot actuator dependency it brings this error
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.camunda.bpm.spring.boot.starter.actuator.ProcessEngineHealthIndicator and org.springframework.util.Assert
